# Select table 3 rows in one line

Tags: php, mysql, row

I have results table need get all Sub_ID inline row Sub_ID (17,18,19) in one row

In a query like this one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `results`
WHERE `ExamID` = 1
```

**Result Table**

```
+----+-------+--------+--------+-------+-------+-------+
| ID | StuID | Sub_ID | ExamID | Exam1 | Exam2 | Exam3 |
+----+-------+--------+--------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 |    70 |     17 |      1 |     0 |     0 |     0 |
|  2 |    70 |     18 |      1 |     0 |     0 |     0 |
|  3 |    70 |     19 |      1 |     0 |     0 |     0 |
|  4 |    70 |     24 |      4 |     0 |     0 |     0 |
|  5 |    70 |     25 |      4 |     0 |     0 |     0 |
+----+-------+--------+--------+-------+-------+-------+
```

**Show Table in Page**

Need to get all Sub_ID inline Where ExamID = 1

How do I write my SQL statement, to get a result like this one?:

```
+----+-------+--------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| ID | StuID | Sub_ID | ExamID | Exam1 | Exam2 | Exam3 | StuID | Exam1 | Exam2 | Exam3 | StuID | Exam1 | Exam2 | Exam3 |
+----+-------+--------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 |    70 |     17 |      1 |     0 |     0 |     0 |    18 |     0 |     0 |     0 |    19 |     0 |     0 |     0 |
+----+-------+--------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

need MySQL query to get that table

Comment: What have u tried? What help do you need? sql statement? php function?  please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: You need to give us some details about what you are trying to accomplish. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you asking for a sql query?

Comment: Are you asking us to write you a complex SQL query with no source query?  If so, then probably not

Comment: I can't use Concat_Group for this table and you didn't need source query

Comment: Seriously consider revising your schema design. Then consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: can you help me for the schema design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use the following query to get similar to the result you requested.

**Solution 1**

> **NOTE :** You wont get the values in column wise but with the comma separated all in one column.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id,',',StuID,',', Sub_ID,',',ExamID,',',Exam1,',',Exam2,',',Exam3) 
FROM `results` 
GROUP BY ExamID
```

**Sample Output :**

```
GROUP_CONCAT(id,',',StuID,',', Sub_ID,',',ExamID,',',Exam1,',',Exam2,',',Exam3)
1,70,17,1,0,0,0,2,70,18,1,0,0,0,3,70,19,1,0,0,0
4,70,20,4,0,0,0,5,70,21,4,0,0,0
```

If you want each and every row to explode after 7th column (considering your columns) then use the following snippet inside **foreach** or **for** loop

```
array_chunk(explode(';', $input), 7);
```

NOTE : Remove the columns which you dont need in the GROUP_CONCAT() of select.

**Solution 2**

If you don't want the result in the above fashion then the only solution would be to fetch all the results from the database table and loop  into them and achieve the thing what you wanted.

**Updated** :

First you need to query for all the records and then perform the action you want. Let me give the small snippet. But again in depends on how you want to achieve.

```
$resultsQuery = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM results");
$finalResults = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($resultsQuery) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultsQuery)){
        /* 
            Here you can write your script

                    OR

            Store the $row in an array and do as per your needs
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain me more the second solution?

Comment: @AhmedMamdouh Hi I have updated my code. Please check it